# How can I check if a file has a red tag label in Finder using Swift on MacOS?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, tags

I am creating my first project for MacOs.
I have to work on files in a folder. My goal is to check these files and see which elements have a red tag applied via Finder.
I am literally going crazy because the code cannot recognise the images with the red tag.

This is the function I have written.

```
 func isFileTaggedRed(at fileURL: URL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let resourceValues = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.labelColorKey])
            if let labelColor = resourceValues.labelColor, labelColor == .red {
                return true
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error retrieving resource values for file: \(error)")
        }
        
        return false
    }
```

This is the code in the ViewController

```
for imageUrl in imageUrls {
            if isFileTaggedRed(at: imageUrl) {
                print("Skipping red tagged image: \(imageUrl.lastPathComponent)")
                continue
            }else{
                print("not tagged")
            }
        }
```

[file info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlQzT.png)

Comment: Well, what label colors are you seeing?

Comment: Isn't label color replaced by tags in 0.9? What if a file has multiple tags or the order of the tags did change?

Comment: This is probably a light/dark mode issue

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is an easier way to accomplish what you need but you can get the fileUrl `tagNames` and check if it contains `"Red"`

---

```
extension URL {
    var isFileTaggedRed: Bool {
        tagNames.contains("Red")
    }
    var tagNames: [String] {
        (try? resourceValues(forKeys: [.tagNamesKey]))?.tagNames ?? []
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let folderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
            .appendingPathComponent("untitled folder", isDirectory: true)

        let files = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)

        if let fileUrl = files.first {
            print("isTaggedRed:", fileUrl.isFileTaggedRed)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used labelColorKey before. It looks like the `labelColor` you get back is an `NSColor`. Colors are tricky in a color-managed system like MacOS. The color may be a shade of red but not the exact color you want. I would suggest logging the RGB values of your returned colors with `NSColor.getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`. You're probably getting back a color that's close to, but not exactly equal to `.red`.

You might need to add code that checks to see if the RGB values are within a "wiggle room" range of .red (say each component is within .01 of the target color.)

### Edit:

I just tried it, and when I added a red label to a file, I got back an NSColor that logs as `NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace 0.980484 0.382818 0.347662 1`

That will look red, but not fully saturated red.

Note that `NSColor.red` logs as `sRGB IEC61966-2.1 colorspace 1 0 0 1` (100% red and no green or blue.)

Furthermore, when I look at a file with a red label, it does look like a slightly washed out red, not pure red.

### Edit #2:

The code I used (in a command line tool) is as follows:

```
func fileColor(at fileURL: URL) -> NSColor? {
       do {
           let resourceValues = try fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: [.labelColorKey])
           if let labelColor = resourceValues.labelColor {
               return labelColor
           }
       } catch {
           print("Error retrieving resource values for file: \(error)")
           return nil
       }
       
       return nil
   }

let path = "~/Documents/RedFile.rtf"
let fixedPath = NSString(string:path).expandingTildeInPath
let fileURL = URL(filePath: fixedPath)

if let fileColor = fileColor(at: fileURL) {
    print("File color returned is \(fileColor)")
} else {
    print("Could not load file.")
}
```